# Unexpected namespace order

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml

Could you please help me with a strange lxml behavior:
I have a xml document and xmlRoot contains such attributes in the following order:

```
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://www.example.com/xs/feed/1.0"
```

Then I'm trying to get namespaces by

```
LocalConf['xmlRoot'] = etree.parse(LocalConf['feedName']).getroot()
print LocalConf['xmlRoot'].nsmap
```

And locally the order is `xsd xsi None`
But on production it is reversed - `None xsi xsd`.

I have no idea what's the problem. LXML version is 3.6.4

Comment: Maybe you're dealing with hashmaps (dictionaries) under the hood. Order is not always guaranteed to remain the same.

Comment: Yes, I am. I know that dict does not guarantee the order, but the order locally Always 1 2 3 and on prod is 3 2 1.

Comment: That's very interesting!

Comment: Is there a different hash seed on prod? https://docs.python.org/2.7/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED